# Android Firebase Dynamic Link character length

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Are Firebase short Dynamic Links guaranteed to be the same character length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see this mentioned in Android docs but iOS docs apply here as well. All platforms will call the same server side shortening API.

Here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create section `Set the length of a short Dynamic Link`.

Long one:

> By default, or if you set the parameter to "UNGUESSABLE", the path
>   component will be a 17-character string

Short one:

> If you set the parameter to "SHORT", the path component will be a
>   string that is only as long as needed to be unique, with a minimum
>   length of 4 characters.

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy. Too bad the docs aren't consistent. 17 characters is what I am seeing though, didn't think to  look at the iOS doc.